# Getting Project name when displaying data from Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am displaying records from Firebase Realtime Database when I was using:

```
     ArrayList<String> list;
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
     adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_white_text,R.id.userInfo, list);
     list.add("Name :"+member.getName().toString()+" Age :"+member.getAge().toString()+" Phone 
  :"+member.getPhone().toString()+"\n"+"------------------------");
```

the record was displaying properly but to pass the data from that activity to another activity I am using:

```
      ArrayList<Member> list;
ArrayAdapter<Member> adapter;
 adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Member>(this,R.layout.list_white_text,R.id.userInfo, list);
list.add(member);
```

but now when displaying i get com.example.project name 
[image]:

My code to display records :

```
  ListView listView;
  FirebaseDatabase database;
  DatabaseReference ref;
 ArrayList<Member> list;
 ArrayAdapter<Member> adapter;
  Member member;
 Button btnDlt;
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_retreivedata);
    member = new Member();
   listView =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    btnDlt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDlt);
   database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
   ref = database.getReference("Member");
   list = new ArrayList<Member>();
   adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Member>(this,R.layout.list_white_text,R.id.userInfo, list);
   ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                     for(DataSnapshot dts: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                     {
                         member = dts.getValue(Member.class);
        list.add(member); // here i want to do list.add(member.getName().toString()); but not allowed
           }
           listView.setAdapter(adapter);
       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
       }
   });
```

My Member Class:

```
public class Member implements Serializable {

private String memberId;
private String Name;
private String Age;
private String Phone;
private String Height;

public Member() {
}

public Member(String memberId, String name, String age, String phone, String height) {
    this.memberId = memberId;
    Name = name;
    Age = age;
    Phone = phone;
    Height = height;
}

public String getMemberId() {
    return memberId;
}

public void setMemberId(String memberId) {
    this.memberId = memberId;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public String getAge() {
    return Age;
}

public void setAge(String age) {
    Age = age;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return Phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    Phone = phone;
}

public String getHeight() {
    return Height;
}

public void setHeight(String height) {
    Height = height;
}
}
```

I want to display data but it is displaying project name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but now when displaying I get com.example.project name

Those two items that are displayed in your emulator are not the "project name", those characters are the addresses of the objects that exist in the memory by the time of their creation. When you create a `List<Member>` objects and you pass it to the adapter, the adapter tries to call `toString()` on all those objects. Since you did **not** override that method in your `Member` class, those addresses are displayed. There are two ways in which you can solve this.

The first one would be to override the `toString()` method in your `Member` class by giving it a proper implementation:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Member{" +
            "memberId='" + memberId+ '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

In this way, you are telling the adapter to display the value of the `memberId` instead of the address in the memory for each object.

The second solution would be to change your adapter, to be of type String. In this way, you should pass a `List<String>` instead of `List<Member>`, a list that should contain as String values, the data that you want to be displayed. If we take as an example, the above property, you should create a list of member IDs. If you need the value of another property, then you should create a list of names, or phone numbers, or you can concatenate more values in a single String.

Answer (score 0):

ArrayAdapter does not understand how to display "Member" Object. So in order to display your data either make a custom array adapter or convert it to "String" object

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ArrayList<String> list
...
   list = new ArrayList<String>();
   adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_white_text,R.id.userInfo, list);
...
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     for(DataSnapshot dts: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
         {
            member = dts.getValue(Member.class);
            list.add(member.getName()+...);
}
```